# Migrating SharePoint Server 2010 to Server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, server, windows-server-2012

Our customer has surprised with a new requirement. We are in the process of moving our SharePoint 2010 environment to a new server with a little more juice. No problem right?

Well we got surprised with a requirement that the new server has to be upgraded to Server 2012 R2. They apparently knew about this requirement months ago, but waited until after we did the install on Server 2008 R2 to tell us about. Brilliant! Thanks a bunch!

I have some concerns about trying to manage a SharePoint 2010 environment on Server 2012 and was hoping I could find someone who can tell me whether their experience has been positive or negative. What pitfalls can I avoid?

Questions

- Are there any noticeable issues with running SP2010 on Server 2012?
- Any installation issues that I should allot more time in project plan to work out?
- Any issues with setting up a SP2010 Development Environment on Server 2012 R2?
- Any issues with custom Asp.net webparts or application pages that migrate into the new environment? Assume that SharePoint 2010    will    still only allow 3.5 framework on the new server right?
- Any issues with migrating the SP 2010 databases into SQL Server 2012?

Thanks for any help. I would love to avoid any more punches to the nose.

Comment: your questions are little confused, are you talking about sql 2012 or sql 2012 R2?

Comment: Ok bottom line. I need to get SharePoint 2010 to run on Server 2012 R2. The SP 2010 databases are currently loaded in SQL Server 2008 r2. It will need to go in to SQL Server 2012 r2 or whatever comes with the windows server. Are there issues moving a content database that existed on SQL Server 2008. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finished this migration, and here is what I ran into.
•Are there any noticeable issues with running SP2010 on Server 2012? 
Yes. IIS is somewhat different which makes the configuration process more complicated. This is especially noticeable when installing FBA. There are no good guides on how to do this. Hint* Use FBA Config Manager to get your configuration files setup. Also use the FBA 2010 pack, and don't be tempted to use 2013.

•Any installation issues that I should allot more time in project plan to work out? 
Not really any more than normal. Every installation has its own set of problems but nothing specific in this case.

•Any issues with setting up a SP2010 Development Environment on Server 2012 R2?
No. Easy.

•Any issues with custom Asp.net webparts or application pages that migrate into the new environment? Assume that SharePoint 2010 will still only allow 3.5 framework on the new server right? 
Old webparts built with .Net 2.0 continued to work fine, but I had issues editing the old ones on the development server because some of the libraries I had used changed.

•Any issues with migrating the SP 2010 databases into SQL Server 2012?

No.